# Select files from google drive and share file in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-shared-drive, android-googleapiclient

I am using google drive api. After selecting files in onActivityResult i am getting uri of drive selected file.

how to get file or driveId using uri. or any other options to select file share in chat window.

Comment: The onActivityResult of which action?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you are picking the file from SAF.
Considering this is what you mean, it is impossible to get the google drive file id from the URI ( the URI you get from the intent from SAF action)

To get the file id you will have to search for the file in the user drive and get the file id from the found file. If this is what you mean, I can help you posting the code for this using java Drive API